# Is MVVM with Prism coded differently than just MVVM by itself?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I recently created an interface with MVVM making sure there was no code behind. Our development team in India reused that interface with some modifications. When I went to use the new UI I found that these modifications seemed to break some of the bindings I had made between the view and viewmodel. I then found this new code below in the view. I have only included part of the code. You can see that the viewmodel is referenced multiple times in the view. I though it was a highly discouraged. I know that having a setter to the viewmodel in the view is something they are always doing with their Prism implementation, but I have never seen actual calls to the viewmodel from the view before. I don't want to bring this up with their supervisor unless I am sure of my position with regards to good coding practice.

```
    [Import]
    public ProfileLimitsViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return DataContext as ProfileLimitsViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            DataContext = value;
            _performSelection = true;
            ViewModel.OnSelectedProfilesChanged -= setSelection;
            ViewModel.OnSelectedProfilesChanged += setSelection;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// On Profile selection changed in UI
    /// </summary>
    private void ProfileList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int count = 0;
            ViewModel.SelectedProfiles.Clear();

            //if multiple profile is selected
            if (ProfileList.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var profile in ProfileList.SelectedItems)
                {
                    ViewModel.SelectedProfiles.Add((profile as ProfileNS).ProfileID);

                    //the profile that is selected
                    if (count++ == 0)
                        ViewModel.SelectedProfile = profile as ProfileNS;
                }
            }

            if (_performSelection)
            {
                ViewModel.SelectedFormationId = ViewModel.SelectedProfile.Layers[0].BedId;
                ViewModel.ProfileSelectionChanged();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Diagnostics.LogHandledException(ex);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// on closed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ProfileEditor_Closed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Event to update ProfileEditor checkbox in ContextualTab
        ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregatorService>().Publish
            <ProfileEditorSelectedEvent, MCWDEditorMode>(MCWDEditorMode.Close);

        ViewModel.ModuleService.UpdateMcwdEditorViewModelsHash(ViewModel.WellLandingId, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// On formation selection changed in UI
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ProfileLayersDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.AddedItems != null && e.AddedItems.Count > 0 && _performSelection)
                ViewModel.FormationSelectionChanged(e.AddedItems[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Diagnostics.LogHandledException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An event handler in C# is a sure sign you are not doing MVVM properly. I'm looking at you, `ProfileList_SelectionChange`. Reference for you/your boss: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx Prism only gives you the tools to do MVVM properly; it does not prevent you from doing things in WinForms style.

Comment: Agreed. It looks like the India-based crowd don't know much about WPF.

Comment: I have quickly looked at your link and it seems like the Viewmodel {get,  set} is standard for Prism, but all the other calls to ViewModel from the view are a no-no.

Comment: The main thing to think about is if you have a View with knowledge of an event that's exposed in a ViewModel, you've created an inappropriate (non-MVVM) dependency. This is why there are, say, Commands and Behaviors exposed by the ViewModel, providing the indirection necessary to decouple the classes.

Comment: Thanks. You have given me the information I need to present to the team lead and get the code fixed.

Comment: I also would recommend your boss or your team to separate Assemblies. Crate a MyApp.ViewModels.dll assembly and put only ViewModels there. Put your view related stuff in a MyApp.UI.dll assembly and your application related stuff in MyApp.Desktop.dll or MyApp.WinPhone.dll etc. depending on platform you do. MyViewModels.dll should **never** have a reference to UI/Desktop assembly and **NEVER** reference Presentation.dll. If for any reason a programmer needs to use anything from Presentation.dll you automatically know, it violates MVVM

Comment: And since you don't have any Reference in your MyApp.ViewModels.dll you won't accidentally use any type from Presentation.dll

Answer (score 0):

Todd Sprang is right, at least partly. There may be legit reasons to use EventHandlers, but the one pointed out by Todd (`ProfileList_SelectionChange`) is definitively not belonging there, neither is `RoutedEventArgs`, as they are both defined in the Presentation.dll.

There are pretty easy ways to enforce this, by splitting your MVVM layers into multiple assemblies.

- MyApp.ViewModels.dll assembly and put only ViewModels there
- Put your view related stuff in a MyApp.UI.dll assembly (Views)
- Application related goes into MyApp.Desktop.dll or MyApp.WinPhone.dll etc. Plattform dependend stuff, WPF, XAML, Silverlight, ASP.NET)

MyViewModels.dll should never have a reference to UI/Desktop assembly and NEVER reference Presentation.dll. If a developer needs to use anything from Presentation.dll you automatically know, it violates MVVM, because you will have a reference to Platform or View specific type in your code